What topic in meta can a layman participate after the name change?
The site is decided to tailor to a more professional target audience.
I'm glad this help the site. Thank you for your endurance and commitment to the site. 
To a certain degree I feel shameful for being able to only take from it, not give anything. But now I'm afraid that I can't be helpful anymore, especially in the meta, in important problems. Being a layman how can I know what is useful to contributing? Will my votes becomes noise, because it is equivalent to a vote of an expert? I used to leave answers and comments on the meta, and they are somewhat useful, but from now what can I do? I can't see anything left for me to do, except asking if a topic is on-topic or not.

Active users are warmly welcomed and encouraged to participate in meta. You only have six active questions and no answers on the main site. On the SE network, site participation is generally quantified in terms of rep (barred the mods who focus their attention sometimes elsewhere than rep mining :-). Because of your small amount of posts, your rep is low. I think you need to think about how involved you are with this site. If you have the feeling it doesn't feel right to participate in certain discussions, then don't. If you think you can add something useful, then please do. 
Lastly, but certainly not least, we are a small SE site. We have been struggling for years to crawl out of beta, without much success. Our site statistics on Area51 are OK'ish, with the biggest hiatus being the #questions asked per day. Long story short, we not only appreciate your involvement, it's also very important for this site's survival. 

I'd like to have an answer addressing more on my expertise. Would it be a noise in where I participate but have no knowledge on it?

@ooker - Then you have to be more specific. Expertise in what? Are you talking meta? Or on the main site? And I think my answer 'If you have the feeling it doesn't feel right to participate in certain discussions, then don't. If you think you can add something useful, then please do' is a rule of thumb here regardless

expertise on the field, but participating in meta. Yes I do agree with it, but also want to have a more specific answer

@Ooker a specific answer needs a specific question. I don't understand what you wish to hear. Honestly.

I've changed the question in the title ("What topic in meta can a layman participate after the name change?"). Is this clearer?
